# Рисование множества объектов Canvas Bitmap View Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, рисование

Всем привет. Есть такая задача (опишу абстрактно, чтобы не срывать покровы) – отображать на ImageView (view with scrollview)  различные геометрические элементы (кружки, квадрты, path`ы) и так же с ними взаимодействовать (максимально примитивно). Элементов много – в районе 1000 + они динамические, хранятся в SVG (можно предложить альтернативный вариант хранения). Я перепробовал такие варианты:

- caverock для отображения svg на ImageView, все классно красиво но zoom ужасно виснет, памяти тоже не мало ест. Отлавливаю нажатие на определенный участок ImageView для отображения информации об объекте
- caverock на bitmap и потом glide, bitmap получается большого размера и часто падает и сжирает очень много памяти и соответственно виснет
- пробовал рисовать на Canvas, переписывать custom view методом onDraw, виснет

Вот отсюда и вопрос – какой способ лучше, есть ли какие нибудь альтернативы? Может кто-то выполнял такую задачу? Для того, чтобы представить задачу детальнее – попробуйте представить карту торгового центра с возможностью нажатия на объекты на ней